# Sublime & Emmet : Best way to unbind and rebind command?

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, emmet

I want to unbind the Emmet Shorcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, and re-bind it to another shortcut.

I can do the rebinding in my `/Packages/user/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` so that when I move this "user" folder to another computer to quickly set up my environment, I have all my shortcuts with me.

But to unbind that command, I just comment-out it (from the `Packages/Emmet/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap`), **which means will be overrided every time I reinstall or update Emmet...**

How to permanently unbind the Emmet shortcut so that it doesn't get reinitialized every time It's updated?

Comment: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#overriding-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: if I unbind it that way, I cannot rebind it to another shortcut !

Comment: You *can* rebind it to anything. This feature only prevents Emmet from handling this shortcut

Comment: Did you actualy tried to do it? I did and once you've added the action name to the disabled action list, even if you rebind it to another shortcut it does not work anymore.

Comment: How you rebind it? Adding new shortcut into user’s keymap file always takes precedence over all other shortcuts: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#merging-and-order-of-precedence

The link I posted above describes how to disable default Emmet shortcuts (e.g. prevent Emmet from handling certain shortcut)

Comment: I have similar issue. Did you solve it? I want to change shortcut for expand_abbreviation from `ctrl`+ `e` to `ctrl`+ `z`. adding exp... to disabled_keymap_actions disables that feature.